# Why some linker-made assembly code is at GOT, instead of PLT?

Tags: assembly, x86, linker, shared-libraries, got

Some library function is shown like below after linking.

```
0x0804842e <+35>:   call   0x80482e0 <printf@plt>
```

So, I understood the usage of `@plt` on disassembly.

However, yesterday, I some some weird code slice.
Below is part of `libstdbuf.s`, which is inclued in `Coreutils`:

```
.L31:
    .loc 1 142 0
    testl   %edi, %edi
    je  .L32
    .loc 1 143 0
    movl    stdin@GOT(%ebx), %eax   # <========= here
    movl    %edi, %edx
```

As you can see, code accesses to `stdin@GOT`.

*Hmm... I've never seen `blabla@GOT` syntax before..*

---

***Question:***

1. What exactly `stdin@GOT(%ebx), %eax` line do?
2. Is this linker-generated code? If *yes*, why is it at `GOT`, instead of `PLT`?
3. And.. How can I know `stdin@GOT` address information?
   *( unlike general global symbols, the address isn't shown on symbol table. See below)*

.

```
jiwon@jiwon$ objdump -t -T ./libstdbuf.so | grep stdin
  00000000       O *UND*    00000000              stdin@@GLIBC_2.0
  00000000      DO *UND*    00000000  GLIBC_2.0   stdin
```

Comment: because it's data, not code.  The PLT (*Procedure* linking table) is only for wrappers around indirect calls to shared library functions.

Comment: See also https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/ for more on PLT vs. global offset table.  And also [What is PLT/GOT?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1992) on RE.SE.